# How do I make turtles recognize other turtles of their same breed in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to build a multi-species model in netlogo. All turtles will have the same movement protocol but their decisions are based off of conspecific densities (number of their breed in a patch), not the full turtle count. Is there a way to get them to recognize members of their own breed without specifically saying 
    count breeda-here

I'm thinking it would be something like

```
 count breed(self?)-here
```

but that's not netlogo syntax. I want them to:
1) count the number of their breed at the current patch
2) count the number of their breed at patches in-radus x

The ultimate goal is to have a single movement protocol for all breeds to reference (instead of an individual movement protocol for each).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine it should work something like this if you just want the agentset returned, as opposed to the count:

```
to-report breed-in-radius [x]
  report other breed in-radius x ;breed is *this* turtle's breed
end
```

Note that because `in-radius` is turtle/patch only (and because we reference turtle variables directly), this would need to be called in turtle context.